# Prevent two users from having the same password

Tags: windows, passwords, active-directory, password-protection

I doubt this is possible and I know this is not the safest idea but I want to see if there is a way in Windows to prevent two users from having the same password.

Specifically I want to make a user have two accounts, one user, one admin, so they may escalate their permissions at will but in the event a malicious program takes hold of their account, they only compromise a user rather than an administrator.

From my understanding password hashes in Windows are not salted, so two passwords should hash to the same. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Note: I would be setting this up with active directory not local users.

Comment: As the password should never be stored anywhere in plaintext, the closest you could get is to prevent 2 hashes matching. That would not necessarily mean the passwords were identical, only that they hash to the same result.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to use a form to create user accounts in pairs and check them plain text if they match then if they check out create or update the two accounts.

Comment: Assign everybody 2 passwords, one for each account. Write them on a post-it & hand one to each user so they can stick it on the side of their monitor. You know they'll do that anyway ;-)

Comment: There is no mechanic built into Windows that will provide this functionality.  Content filtering should be used to prevent malicious programs from accessing your network

Comment: Assign them different passwords that you don't tell them about and which they can't change—and then set up biometric security. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking salts, use policies to drive this behavior.

If I were attempting to keep people who have both regular and admin accounts from using the same passwords I'd do the following:

The regular user account has more normal password length and complexity requirement:

- 8 character minimum
- at least 1 each special, numeral, -case characters
- expires every 90 days
- password memory is 20
- etc

The admin account password has much more stringent requirements:

- 15 character minimum
- at least 2 or 3 each of special, numeral, -case characters
- expires every 45 days
- password memory is 50
- etc

Doing this does not prevent people from using the same password, but makes it difficult to keep them the same.

Comment: Definitely they'll use post-its... ;)

Comment: Assuming only qualified tech professionals get admin accounts, writing down passwords is grounds for immediate dismissal with prejudice.

Comment: And for non-admins who write their passwords down, immediately disable their accounts, reset their pwds, and inform their supervisors, business units, and HR. Do random sweeps.

Comment: That will just drive them underground; diaries, phone lock screens, backs of envelopes kept in drawers, post-its inside their clothing  lockers... [I'm joking, but I'm not. Soon as you make it too complex, they'll write it down.]

Comment: This is what I anticipated would end up being needed. I was hoping to keep things a little bit easier for users while still keeping the admin account secure. Since we already have a pretty tough password policy, if we made the admin one stronger, we'd end up resetting admin passwords hundreds of times per day.

Comment: It's possible, but these are (more or less) the actual rules I operate under, and while I can't say for certainty about ALL my coworkers, those I know for certain do not write them down.

Comment: if they don't write it down, then they make memorable patterns. Last month it was Fabulous23Marvellous. This month it's Marvellous23Fabulous...

Comment: Sometimes people just overthink password complexity so it's not really that hard to make it cryptic within the policy yet easy for them to remember even if changing frequently. User Jonathan Smith may be jsmith username with a password of `Jon@than#00` for example. Next 90 days he can cycle the last two digits to `11` or `01` and keep it moving as such.... LOL I've had access to government medical systems where it forces two consecutive characters from being the same on next password change but usually with AD policies for normal users and complexity, many just overthink it.